# How to have dynamic multiple dropdown with vue-multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-multiselect

Hi  i don't know whether what i'm trying to achieve is possible or not with vue  for a particular component by changing its data and loading automatically

**Below is my expection(tried in jquery)**

```js
var data = {country:{type:'dropdown',values:['india','usa']},money:{type:'input',placeholder:'enter amount'},india:['Bengaluru'],usa:['Silicon Valley']}


function getDropTemplate(dropDownList){
    var dropDownStr = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < dropDownList.length; i++){
       dropDownStr += `<option value="${dropDownList[i]}">${dropDownList[i]}</option>`
    }
   return `<select class="mainCountry">${dropDownStr}</select>`;
}

function getInputTemplate(inputObj){
   return `<input type="text" placeholder="${inputObj.placeholder}"/>`
}


$(function(){
    
   $('#dropdown').on('change',function(){
      var value = $(this).val(), template = '';
      if(data[value].type == 'dropdown'){
           template += getDropTemplate(data[value].values)
      }else{
          template += getInputTemplate(data[value])
      }

      $('#selectedResults').html(template);
   });

   $(document).on('change','.mainCountry',function(){
      var result = data[$(this).val()]
      $('#subResults').html(getDropTemplate(result));
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<select id="dropdown">
   <option value="">--select--</option>
   <option value="money">Money</option>
   <option value="country">Country</option>
</select>

<div id="selectedResults">

</div>

<div id="subResults">

</div>
```

From above snippet you can observe that by selecting `country -> india -> Bengaluru` or `country -> usa -> Silicon Valley`

I want to replicate the same thing with  `vue-multiselect`

**below is what i have tried in vue**

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default },
  data () {
    return {
      value: [],
       //data:{country:{type:'dropdown',values:['india','usa']},money:{type:'input',placeholder:'enter amount'},india:['Bengaluru'],usa:['Silicon Valley']}

       options:[{name:'money'},{name:'country'}]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  
  


<div id="app">

     <multiselect
    v-model="value"
     track-by="name"
    :options="options"
    label="name"
     :multiple="false"
    :taggable="false"
  ></multiselect>
  

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could conditionally render the `input` or `multiselects` based on `category.name`.

For instance, when `category.name` is `Money`, show the `<input>`:

```html
<template v-if="category && category.name === 'Money'">
  <input type="text" v-model="moneyAmount" placeholder="Enter amount">
</template>
```

Otherwise, when it's `Country`, show two `multiselect`s (one for country selection, and the other for region):

```html
<template v-else-if="category && category.name === 'Country'">
  <multiselect
               placeholder="Select a country"
               v-model="country"
               track-by="name"
               :options="countryOptions"
               label="name"
               :multiple="false"
               :taggable="false">
  </multiselect>

  <multiselect v-if="country && country.regions"
               placeholder="Select a region"
               v-model="region"
               :options="country.regions"
               :multiple="false"
               :taggable="false">
  </multiselect>
</template>
```

The country `multiselect` is populated with `countryOptions[]` (shown below), each of which has `regions[]`, which is used to populate the region `multiselect`. This ensures the displayed regions are only applicable to the selected country.

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      category: null,
      country: null,
      region: null,
      moneyAmount: null,
      categoryOptions: [{ name: 'Money' }, { name: 'Country' }],
      countryOptions: [
        {
          name: 'USA',
          regions: ['Silicon Valley', 'Midwest'],
        },
        {
          name: 'India',
          regions: ['Bengaluru'],
        }
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/MWmbzQw)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to conditionally render a component based on the option you select from the dropdown?

If so why not use a v-if - see how to conditionally render components in the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

```
<template v-if="country.value === 'usa'">
    // render input for USA
</template>
<template v-else-if="country.value === 'india'">
    // render input for India
</template>
```

Comment: if you replicate the jquery working example that would be better